# Как обернуть изображение в круг?

Tags: css, css3, svg, css-animation

Обернуть изображение в круг, я пытался сделать это с помощью padding'а, после чего добавив обыкновенные границы, но это портит изображение по углам.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: С помощью border, border-radius и тд. Почитайте тут http://htmlbook.ru/css/border

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/50/50" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
.block {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <img src="https://www.placecage.com/120/120" alt="image">
</div>
```

Не очень понял, что именно у тебя не вышло. Но по твоему описанию, у меня получилось

Answer (score 2):

### SVG mask

Как вариант решения, применение SVG mask для вырезания круглого изображения. 
Применение маски дает возможность более интересно сделать границу полупрозрачной.
Применение SVG делает изображение полностью адаптивным к любому размеру гаджета.

**Работает во всех современных браузерах включая IE11, Edge**

Вариант с анимацией не работает в IE11, Edge.

```css
.simpson {
background: rgb(238,174,202);
background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(238,174,202,1) 0%, rgba(148,208,233,1) 100%);
}
svg {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
.container {
width:25%;
height:25%;
display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="simpson">
 
 <div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 230 230" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
 <defs>
   
  <mask id="msk1"> 
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />
   <circle cx="110" cy="110" r="100" fill="white" stroke-width="15" stroke="grey"  />
  </mask>
</defs>
  

<image id="img" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vN9Ni.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#msk1)" />
</svg>  
</div> 
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 230 230" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
 <defs>
   
  <mask id="msk1"> 
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />
   <circle cx="110" cy="110" r="100" fill="white" stroke-width="15" stroke="grey"  />
  </mask>

 </defs> 

<image id="img" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/96s42.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#msk1)" />
</svg>  
</div>
</div>
```

**Вариант с анимацией вращения картинок при наведении**

Кнопка становится выпуклой за счёт добавления тени.

```css
.simpson {
background: rgb(238,174,202);
background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(238,174,202,1) 0%, rgba(148,208,233,1) 100%);
}
.container {
width:25%;
height:25%;
display: inline-block;

}
svg {
width:100%;
height:100%;
 
}
svg:hover {
filter:drop-shadow(2px 4px 7px black) ;
}
#img {
transform-origin:110px 110px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease-in-out;
          transition:         transform 1s ease-in-out;
}

#img:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
          transform: rotate(360deg);
    
}
```

```html
<div class="simpson">
 
 <div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 230 230" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
 <defs>
   
  <mask id="msk1"> 
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />
   <circle cx="110" cy="110" r="100" fill="white" stroke-width="7" stroke="grey"  />
  </mask>
</defs>
  

<image id="img" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vN9Ni.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#msk1)" />
</svg>  
</div> 

 <div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 230 230" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
 <defs>
   
  <mask id="msk1"> 
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />
   <circle cx="110" cy="110" r="100" fill="white" stroke-width="10" stroke="grey"  />
  </mask>
</defs>
  

<image id="img" x="-15px" y="-15px" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTW7g.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#msk1)" />
</svg>  
</div> 
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 230 230" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
 <defs>
   
  <mask id="msk1"> 
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />
   <circle cx="110" cy="110" r="100" fill="white" stroke-width="10" stroke="grey"  />
  </mask>

 </defs> 

<image id="img" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/96s42.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#msk1)" />
</svg>  
</div>
</div>
```